# Save filepath to access on homepage

Tags: sharedpreferences, shortcut

I am very new at making apps, this being my 3rd week, and I'm not sure the syntax needed to make my idea work.

When the first button is clicked I want it to save the class that is the destination (in this case OddesyYears but could be any random class) to be saved/remembered before going to the intent.

```
            Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);                
            button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                      

                public void onClick(View v) {

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("key", "OddesyYears");
                    editor.commit();


                    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),OddesyYears.class);
                    startActivity(i);
```

Then at a later time after app has been closed/turned off and reopened...

```
        public void onClick(View v) {


        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String MyCar = sharedPreferences.getString("key", "RandomClass");  

         If (MyCar == null)
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Please Select from other window", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        elseIf()
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MyCar.class);
            startActivity(i);
```

The class will be remembered and accessed from another button for the life of the app. This will remain empty until something is saved then access the saved location when the user wants. I'm trying to pass it as a string which is failing miserably and not sure where else to turn. Maybe intent.shortcut?

I also want this to remain fairly generic since the user can choose to access many different classes and each time one is chosen it will write over the old one.

Much thanks!